# STORED PROCEDURE CONVERT ERROR

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Have stored procedure where i want update data and want cast some varbinary to nvarchar

```
UPDATE [payterm].[dict_default_values]
SET    [default_value] = CAST(@value AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
      ,[descr] = CAST(@descr AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
      ,[grp] = @grp
WHERE  [code] = @code;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO [payterm].[dict_default_values]
      ([code], [default_value], [descr], [grp])
    VALUES
      (@code, @value, @descr, @grp);
```

When i put parametrs  there were error : **Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query**

Comment: If @ value and @ descr are input parameters, why not simply make them varchar so you don't have to cast anything?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to cast in the VALUES part of your INSERT statement.

Without knowing the data types of your variable/parameters/columns it's difficult to give a specific answer though.

Comment: Not if you don't first give me the types of all variables/parameters/columns.

Comment: thank you I solve this problem , there were problem in backend not in database